# Count occurences in a cell, with a condition- R studio

Tags: r, string

I have a string like this one:

```
0|294|314|20|314|SC49TST57ASG75A|1428.0
```

Using R, I want to extract only the data between two `|` (example- `SC49TST57ASG75A`), and then count only the numbers which are bigger than 20 (in this case I have the numbers 49,57,75 so the code needs to return the number 3)

I want to apply it on a column in a data frame.
Eventually, I want to get a new column that specify for each row how many numbers that are greater than 20 there is inside the |....|.

Thanks!

Comment: which language are you using and what have you tried so far?

Comment: sorry for didn't mention, I'm using R, and I've tried str_extract and str_trim, and a lot of other functions but I can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: IMHO, it may be worth trying to clarify what you want. For instance, you can identify what are the 3 numbers the code should return, here I think it is `294`, `314` and `314`. `1428.0` is exluded because it's not followed by `|` and `20` is excluded because it is not `>20` (so, you meant *strickly* bigger than 20).

Answer (score 1):

You can try `strsplit` with split = `'\\|'`, if you only want to count between two pipes then you should exclude the first and the last elements also since you want elements greater than 20 ( we are using > sign for clarity in the solution)

I am assuming here that your columns have same structure as given in your question.

```
st <- '0|294|314|20|314|SC5GSC12ASG266T|1428.0'
```

**Solution:**

```
lapply(strsplit(st, '\\|'), function(x)sum(as.numeric(x[2:(length(x)-1)]) > 20, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: I was thinking about this way, there is just one problem if `st` ends with a `|`, one value can be missed. But this might never be the case, depends on the dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm trying to run this code but it doesn't work on a data frame, my raw data is a data table and i also want my result to be a column that has the count for each row. I'm basically counting the number of mutations I have that are not in the first 20 nucleotides positions.

Comment: @LigalMaimon , what do you mean by "it doesn't work", what error it is showing or what do you expect where it mismatches with value, with whatever input you have given it works, so in case its not matching with desired output, please point out the mismtach, that is why it always  good to write full question with expected outcome, Edit your question accordingly, with input, expected output and the mismatch you are getting, otherwise its difficult to help

Comment: I think my question wasn't clear, it is now been edited :) I want to count the numbers inside the pipes and the code counts the numbers that are outside the pipes. thanks again.

Comment: @LigalMaimon , the code given as answer should also work with a column, for example, suppose if your dataframe is `df` and column is `C` then you can create, `df$C_new <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$C, '\\|'), function(x)sum(as.numeric(x[2:(length(x)-1)]) > 20, na.rm=TRUE)))`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, otherwise please tell me what is your expected result.

```
cnt <- Map(function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)>20), 
    regmatches(r <- unlist(regmatches(s,gregexpr("(?<=\\|).*?(?=\\|)",s,perl = TRUE))),
               gregexpr("\\d+\\.?\\d+?",r)))
```

such that

```
> cnt
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 0

[[4]]
[1] 1

[[5]]
[1] 1
```

**DATA**

```
s <- "0|294|314|20|314|SC5GSC12ASG266T|1428.0"
```

Comment: I will simplify the problem: I have a string like this: SA36CST52GSG90, I want to count how many numbers in this string are bigger than 20, in this case, the result should be: 3. thanks!

Comment: @LigalMaimon if you all have numbers in the string as integers, maybe you can try `length(Filter(function(x) as.numeric(x)>20,unlist(strsplit(s,"\\D"))))`, which gives `3` when you input is `s <- "SA36CST52GSG90"`

Comment: Thanks, that's working great, the only question now is how to apply it on a data frame, so I would get a new column, with the count for each one of the rows... I know apply function can do it but I'm not sure how to use it

Comment: @LigalMaimon you can use `sapply`, e.g., `df$count <- sapply(df$s, function(v)  length(Filter(function(x) as.numeric(x)>20,unlist(strsplit(v,"\\D")))))`, where `df$s` is the column with your strings, and `df$count` is the counts